# Dúvida de como adicionar objeto em um Array no Angular

Tags: angular

Tô aprendendo Angular e estou criando um método que vai adicionar um objeto em um Array para visualizar no html utilizando a diretiva NgFor.

O erro está na parte que do **funcionario.push({})**

```
export class AppComponent {
  UltimoId = 0;
  nome = "";
  adicionado = false
  funcionarios : string[] = [];

  adiciona(){
  console.log(`Adicionado ${this.nome}`)
  this.adicionado = true;
  this.funcionarios.push({
    nome : this.nome,
    id : ++this.UltimoId
  });
}
```

Meu Erro

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:21:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ nome: string; id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

21 



this.funcionarios.push({
                            ~
22     nome : this.nome,
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
23     id : ++this.UltimoId
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
24   });
   ~~~
```

Comment: `funcionarios : string[] = [];` funcionarios tem que ser um array de Strings, logo se tentar fazer um push de um objeto, vai dar erro. Nesse caso, crie uma interface para esse objeto e atribua à funcionarios. Exemplo: `funcionarios : FuncObject[] = [];`, ou use o `any` (não recomendado): `funcionarios : any[] = [];`

Comment: Crie uma interface para esse objeto. Ex: `interface  FuncObject {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
}` e use em `funcionarios : FuncObject[] = [];`

Comment: Beleza! Valeu obrigado.